# Is the GNU C++ compiler ((GCC) 5.2.0) good at "inlining" by itself?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++14

I'm not asking why or when I should use `inline` in some code.

I use `inline` where I think it's usual (like in get/set functions). I read on stack some unusual example where `inline` sounds necessary. I'm not sure that I'll recognize a such situation in my code... I mean, until I get an issue...

So I wonder if for usual cases the compiler handles that as well as I do, maybe even better...

The reason why I would like to avoid `inline`, is to avoid having to implement in the headers ... About that a question pop in my mind:

is the compiler (I always consider the GCC compiler in my question) able to `inline` a function not implemented in the header ?

n.b. : I don't know if there is some internal changes about `inline` in C++14.

Comment: If you implement a non inline function at a header you'll get a linker error for multiply defined symbol when including it from multiple source files

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou well, I don't want to implement in the header... as I wrote it in the question

Comment: @juanchopanza, "Is/Does...?" I bet on does, I lost...

Comment: You're talking about 'inline' methods, i.e., implemented in the class definition?

Comment: @bob I mean "you inline because you implement in the header" you don't "implement in the header because you  inline" : inline implementations can exist in cpp files. There are cases where you don't have a choice (are a matter of syntax and correctness). For example a function template has to be implemented in the header but doesn't need the inline keyword. Apart from these you should define what your metrics are for "goodness"

Comment: gcc cannot inline functions from another compilation unit unless you use link time optimization (via the -flto flag for compiling and linking) - but in that case, it does quite a good job at it.

Comment: thx to everyone for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some kind of example code, it's VERY hard to say for sure what the compiler will do (even WITH code, it can be pretty darn difficult).

Generally speaking, if the function is small, the compiler will inline functions that have their source code available during compilation (and others if you enable lto (link time optimisation). If you expect to be able to compile a function into an object file and get the function inlined, then you HAVE to use lto.

A function that is large and static, called only once will also be inlined in most cases.

The problem comes when you have several calls and the function is "more than tiny in size" - in other words more than 3-4 lines long. Then the compiler has to balance between inlining and bloating the code, and not inlining and the cost of calls. This is a very difficult balance to get right. Profile-driven optimisation can help a lot here, but in general, the compiler will MOSTLY get it right, but not at all guaranteed - if in doubt (and it's important), use a benchmark of your application, and measure whether it gets better with a force inline attribute.

Comment: I didn't added code, because as you said, "even WITH code, it can be pretty darn difficult". and (maybe I wrong by thinking it's obvious) but get/set function don't take more that one line. I never used `lto` flag so far, I will consider it in the futur. Thx for you anwser

Comment: Typically, for gettter/setter functions, I inline them into the class declaration. That way, they are available for the compiler to inline.

Comment: I use to inline them too, but sometime you have to deal with forward declaration... dependecies... I try to make my headers lighter as possible.

Comment: Sure, and as I said, if performance is very important, benchmark, profile and check where the code is actually spending time. Most functions are only called a few times, and it really doesn't matter much...

Comment: I'm not really aware about how to perform a good benchmark. This is something I have to add on my "to study" list.

Comment: A benchmark would just be doing something that resembles what the program would normally do, and measure how long it takes (either "time from start to finish", or "how many things per second"). This can be for the WHOLE program, or some portions. In my compiler project, I have an option to output "how long did it take" for various steps of the compilation, and use that to determine if I made it better or worse with some change [although I typically care much more about making it do more things or do something better]

Answer (score 3):

First of all inlining something ie requiring inline substitution of the function body at the point of call **doesn't mean that the implementation is constrained to do so** :

> 7.1.2 Function specifiers
>
> 2 A function declaration (8.3.5, 9.3, 11.3) with an inline specifier declares an inline function. The inline specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism. **An implementation is not required to perform this inline substitution at the point of call**; however, even if this inline substitution is omitted, **the other rules for inline functions defined by 7.1.2 shall still be respected.**

This alone should give a taste that it's a fuzzy heuristic to rely on compiler optimizations (or that it matters doing so) regarding this topic. For example we know that the compiler has a hard time inlining function pointer calls but this is not of much importance.

There are some examples of language constructs that the Standard mandates to be inlined and this not a matter of being a good compiler but a compliant one.

### Function Call operators of closure types

> 5.1.2
>
> 5 The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression has a public inline function call operator (...) For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function call operator member template (...)

### constexpr functions

> 7.1.5
>
> 2 (...) constexpr functions and constexpr constructors are implicitly
>   inline (7.1.2).

### Deleted functions

> 8.4.3
>
> A deleted function is implicitly inline. [ Note: The one-definition rule (3.2) applies to deleted definitions.
>   — end note ] A deleted definition of a function shall be the first declaration of the function or, for an explicit
>   specialization of a function template, the first declaration of that specialization.

Other examples are member functions defined inside the class definition and a function defined in a friend declaration of a class. Inlining is not the best choice in every case (can increase program size) so for performance critical section I'd suggest benchmarking and deciding yourself; after all [Do inline functions improve performance?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-and-perf)

Comment: thx for your answer! actualy I never used `constexpr` function and I don't know yet what is a "deleted function". Also I have to read carefully your article about "Do inline functions improve performance?" you deserve +1!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can inline a function used in the same file (technically, "compilation unit") but not when compiling different files, since it doesn't have the source.  That's why inline functions should be placed in the header file.

Comment: "but not when compiling different files" - not true, see `-flto`.